# Time Complexity for finding Discrete Logarithm (brute-force)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, logarithm

I'm trying to understand the time complexity (Big-O) of the following algorithm which finds `x` such that `g^x = y (mod p)` (i.e. finding the discrete logarithm of y with base g modulo p).

Here's the pseudocode:

```
discreteLogarithm(y, g, p)
    y := y mod p
    a := g
    x := 1

    until a = y
        a := (a * g) mod p
        x++

    return x
end
```

I know that the time complexity of this approach is **exponential in the number of binary digits in p** - but what does this mean and why does it depend on p?

I understand that the complexity is determined by the number of loops (`until a = y`), but where does p come into this, what's this about binary digits?

Comment: For the right value of g, a will run in a wild pattern through all the values from 1 to p-1. So if you try all possible values of y, the number of iterations will take on all possible values from 1 to p-1. On the average, p/2.

Answer (score 2):

The run time depends upon the [order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) of g mod p.  The worst case is order (p-1)/2, which is O(p).  The run time is thus O(p) modular multiplies.  The key here is that p has log p bits, where I use 'log' to mean base 2 logarithm.  Since p = 2^( log p ) -- mathematical identity -- we see the run time is exponential in the number of bits of p.  To make it more clear, let's use b=log p to represent the number of bits.  The worst case run time is O(2^b) modular multiplies.  Modular multiplies take O(b^2) time, so the full run time is O(2^b * b^2) time.  The 2^b is the dominant term.

Depending upon your particular p and g, the order could be much smaller than p.  However, some heuristics in analytical number theory show that on average, it is order p.

EDIT: If you are not familiar with the concept of 'order' from group theory, here is brief explanation.  If you keep multiplying g by itself mod p, it eventually comes to 1.  The order is the number of multiplies before that happens.